# switch doesn't find column from uploaded file, unless the uploaded file was created simultaneously

Tags: r

If I run this code, we get the Error: object 'AB' not found. But if we remove the ## from the code (which recreates the file before uploading it) this problem doesn't occur. Also tableOutput finds the file, and if we call the column name instead of tab_input1() there's no issues with the file. I've also made sure that the file is saved to my computer and I've tried writing it as a csv and tsv file.

By removing the switch and instead making the input choices exactly as they are in the column removes the problem. This would however be an ugly fix.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("Experiment 1",
           verticalLayout(fluidRow(
             column(4, selectInput(inputId = "y_axis1", label = "Y-axis",
                         choices = c("a or", "b")))
           ),
             plotlyOutput("experiment1_plot"),
           tableOutput("table_example")
           )
  )
)
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #AB <- c(1, 3, 5)
  #B <- c(2, 4, 6)
  #C <- c(10, 20, 30)
  #my_df <- data.frame(AB, B, C)
  #saveRDS(my_df, "data/test.rds")
  testing_df <- readRDS("data/test.rds")

  tab_input1 <- reactive({
    switch(input$y_axis1,
           "a or" = AB,
           "b" = B)
  })

  output$table_example <- renderTable(testing_df$AB)

  output$experiment1_plot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(testing_df) +
              geom_point(aes(x = tab_input1(), B)) + 
              expand_limits(x=0, y=0)
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

my sessionInfo()

```
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plotly_4.9.0    forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.3     purrr_0.3.2     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_0.8.3     tibble_2.1.3   
 [9] ggplot2_3.2.0   tidyverse_1.2.1 shiny_1.3.2    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.5  haven_2.1.1       lattice_0.20-38   colorspace_1.4-1  generics_0.0.2    vctrs_0.2.0       htmltools_0.3.6  
 [8] viridisLite_0.3.0 yaml_2.2.0        rlang_0.4.0       later_0.8.0       pillar_1.4.2      glue_1.3.1        withr_2.1.2      
[15] modelr_0.1.5      readxl_1.3.1      munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.0      cellranger_1.1.0  rvest_0.3.4       htmlwidgets_1.3  
[22] labeling_0.3      crosstalk_1.0.0   httpuv_1.5.1      broom_0.5.2       Rcpp_1.0.2        xtable_1.8-4      promises_1.0.1   
[29] scales_1.0.0      backports_1.1.4   jsonlite_1.6      mime_0.7          hms_0.5.0         digest_0.6.20     stringi_1.4.3    
[36] grid_3.6.1        cli_1.1.0         tools_3.6.1       magrittr_1.5      lazyeval_0.2.2    crayon_1.3.4      pkgconfig_2.0.2  
[43] zeallot_0.1.0     data.table_1.12.2 xml2_1.2.1        lubridate_1.7.4   assertthat_0.2.1  httr_1.4.1        rstudioapi_0.10  
[50] R6_2.4.0          nlme_3.1-140      compiler_3.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `renderTable` should include the reactive that is used to select the column. So instead of `renderTable(testing_df$AB)` you need `renderTable(testing_df[,tab_input1()])`

Edit: a working app (on my end at least)

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# AB <- c(1, 3, 5)
# B <- c(2, 4, 6)
# C <- c(10, 20, 30)
# my_df <- data.frame(AB, B, C)
# saveRDS(my_df, "test.rds")
testing_df <- readRDS("test.rds")

ui <- fluidPage(tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("Experiment 1",
           verticalLayout(fluidRow(
             column(4, selectInput(inputId = "y_axis1", label = "Y-axis",
                                   choices = c("a or", "b")))
           ),
           plotlyOutput("experiment1_plot"),
           tableOutput("table_example")
           )
  )
)
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  tab_input1 <- reactive({
    switch(input$y_axis1,
           "a or" = "AB",
           "b" = "B")
  })

  output$table_example <- renderTable(testing_df[,tab_input1()])

  output$experiment1_plot <- renderPlotly({
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(testing_df) +
        geom_point(aes(x = tab_input1(), B)) + 
        expand_limits(x=0, y=0)
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Problem's not with the table, but the plot. I tried adapting your method  
    geom_point(aes(x = testing_df[,tab_input1], y = C)) 
but that didn't work either

Comment: Your version doesn't quite work. It plots the AB and B as 1. hugo-pa over at rstudio community managed a fix using your idea of putting testing_df[, tab_input1()] but placed it inside the plotting: geom_point(aes(x = testing_df[, tab_input1()].  
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

hugo-pa over at rstudio community managed a fix, credit goes to him. I've made some slight changes to his answer to better fit this post, as I made the one over at rstudio community after getting some help from @teofil and adapting his answer. To changes were required to fix my issue. First change I made by adapting @teofil 's answer into the plotting part:

```
output$experiment1_plot <- renderPlotly({
    our_df <- table_input()
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(our_df) +
        geom_point(aes(x = our_df[,tab_input1()], y = C)) + 
        expand_limits(x=0, y=0)
    )
  })
```

Second change with an excellent explanation from hugo-pa:

First, I'd like to explain why the error doesn't occur when you uncomment the ## lines: as you know, these lines create the data frame and then save it to a file; however, prior to creating the data frame, the objects AB, B, and C, are all created within the scope of the server function. Therefore, the switch() call in your tab_input1 reactive expression is able to locate the objects AB and B. Thus, it is not the act of saving the data frame to the file before loading it that resolves the error, but rather the assignment of the AB and B variables that does.

The switch statement must be updated in order to completely fix it, as so:

```
switch(input$y_axis1,
       "a or" = "AB",
       "b" = "B")
```

Again, the reason you must do this is that, when you load the object from the test.rds file, you are only loading in the data frame that was saved in it (i.e. my_df; this is because saveRDS() only saves a single R object to a file), and not the variables that were used to create it. Thus, in order to get the data you want, you must extract it from the data frame.